# Paypal PHP SDK create multiple authorization on a order

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

Hello I'm trying to create multiple authorization to a order created using PayPal PHP SDK
I just have this case presented on PayPal official documentation

> For example, when a merchant ships items from multiple distribution centers and needs separate authorizations for each shipment. Another example would be delayed shipping on items that are not in stock.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/create-process-order/#create-the-order

According to this I have until 10 authorization per order but is not what I'm getting...

I can create an order for 20 USD after that I create an autorization for this order to block partial amount of money (10 USD) Everything ok, but when I'm trying to create another authorization for any amount using the same way I created the first one I get this error MAXIMUM_AUTHORIZATION_ALLOWED_REACHED_FOR_ORDER ...  I don't know why because is just the second authorization so I don't know if there is something that I'm missing.

This is the code

- Creating an Order

  ```
  // Amount
  $amount = new Amount();
  $amount->setCurrency("USD")->setTotal(20);

  // Transaction
  $transaction = new Transaction();
  $transaction
      ->setAmount($amount)
      ->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid())
  ;

  // Payer
  $payer = new Payer();
  $payer->setPaymentMethod("paypal");

  // Redirect urls
  $redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
  $redirectUrls
      ->setReturnUrl($successUrl)
      ->setCancelUrl($cancelUrl)
  ;
  // Payment 
  $payment = new Payment();
  $payment
      ->setIntent("order")
      ->setPayer($payer)
      ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
      ->setTransactions(array($transaction))
  ;

  try {
      $paymentResponse = $payment->create($apiContext);
  } catch (Exception $ex) {
      dump($ex);
      exit(1);
  }
  ```
- Excecute an order

  ```
  // Get Payment
  $payment = Payment::get('PAY-3FL894366A430123HK6H765A', $apiContext);
  $transactions = $payment->getTransactions();

  // Create execution
  $execution = new PaymentExecution();
  $execution->setPayerId('DW4YPSRV6HRDS');
  $execution->addTransaction($transactions[0]);

  try {
      // Execute to hold payer's balance
      $result = $payment->execute($execution, $apiContext);           

      // Get payment's autorization
      $resultTransaction = $result->getTransactions()[0];
      $authorization = $resultTransaction->getRelatedResources()[0]->getAuthorization();

  } catch (PayPalConnectionException $e) {
      dump($e);   
      die;
  }
  ```
- Create an authorization

  ```
  $authorization = new Authorization();
  $authorization->setAmount(new Amount(
      '{
          "total": "1.00",
          "currency": "USD"
       }'
  ));
  try {
      $result = $order->authorize($authorization, $apiContext);
  } catch (PayPalConnectionException $e) {
      dump($e); 
  }
  ```